# IntelliJ IDEA - Show Last Commit Information in Project Tool View Like Subclipse

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

In eclipse with the Subclipse plugin, I can see within the project tree view when a file was last changed in SVN as well as who changed it last. Is there a way to accomplish this in IntelliJ Idea without having to go through the history tool?